# Java using the & symbol in Print statements

Tags: java

I am trying to auto generate a UPS label using XML.

I am generating a response in java that is coming back as

```
http://wwwapps.ups.com/WebTracking/track?track=yes&amp;trackNums=1Z9422410395881216
```

But yet i am setting the link to be

```
http://wwwapps.ups.com/WebTracking/track?track=yes&trackNums=1Z9422410395881216
```

How do i stop it from showing up at `&amp` and instead having it show up as just the `&` symbol?

Comment: Please show us your code.

Comment: how are you generating the response?  it looks like whatever tool you're using is automatically encoding your string.

Comment: what's wrong with `&amp;`? in XML, & symbol must be specified as `&amp;`. Otherwise it would not be valid XML.

Comment: The `&` characters have been "escaped" to `&amp;` tokens to distinguish from the `&` characters uses in the XML.  This is normal.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't change the way you read your XML data then maybe try using `unescapeXml` method from `StringEscapeUtils` class from apache commons

```
String address = "http://wwwapps.ups.com/WebTracking/track?track=yes&amp;trackNums=1Z9422410395881216";
System.out.println(StringEscapeUtils.unescapeXml(address));
```

result

```
http://wwwapps.ups.com/WebTracking/track?track=yes&trackNums=1Z9422410395881216
```

Answer (score 0):

What you see is correct XML output, `&` should be specified as `&amp;` for it to be proper XML. You shouldn't change it, or else any XML parser should fail on it.